# Why there is Line Error in LST Image in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, land-surface-temperature

I am working with LST (Land Surface Temperature) in GEE using Landsat 8, but the result after exporting and downloading the map shows some line errors on it. I do not understand the problem because the natural color of Landsat 8 does not show any line error.
I am using this code, but is it correct or wrong? Or is there some step that I should write in my code to solve this problem?

```js
Map.centerObject(layer,12)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Compute NDVI and LTS

function cloudmask(col){
var cloudShadowBitMaskX = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMaskX = (1 << 5)
  var qa = col.select('pixcel_qa');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMaskX).eq(0)
  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMaskX).eq(0));
  return col.updateMask(mask);
}

var col = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
.filterDate('2021-01-01', '2021-12-31')
.filterBounds(layer)
.median();

var ndviX = col.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('NDVI')
Map.addLayer(ndviX)

var min = ee.Number(ndviX.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
  geometry: layer,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels:1e10
}).values().get(0))

var max = ee.Number(ndviX.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  geometry: layer,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels:1e10
}).values().get(0))

var pv = (ndviX.subtract(min).divide(max.subtract(min))).pow(ee.Number(2))

Map.addLayer(pv)

var a = ee.Number(0.004)
var b = ee.Number(0.986)

var EM = pv.multiply(a).add(b).rename('EMM')

var termal = col.select('B10').multiply(0.1)

var LTS = termal.expression(
  '(T/(1+(0.00115*(T/1.438))*log(e)))-273.15',{
  'T':termal.select('B10'),
  'e':EM.select('EMM')
}).rename('LTS');

Map.addLayer(LTS)

    Export.image.toDrive({
    image: LTS,
    scale: 30,
    description: 'LST21.con',
    region: layer
  });
```

---

The code is here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/130ca0cc1393345e582b6f8a7eb70687